# get sparkConf inside map function

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

How to get SparkConf or JavaSparkContext inside a map function in java spark api.

```
     SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application");
     JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
     JavaRDD<String>dateRDD=javaRDD.map(new Function<String, String>() {
```

how to get this sparkconf or context inside this function.shall i pass this as an argument to the constructor.Is there any other way.

Answer (score -1):

You are misunderstanding the Spark concept. `map` function is executed in a set of separate tasks performed on the executor nodes within a separate JVM threads. You should never use `SparkContext` inside of the `map` or any other transformation or action, because bringing up the `SparkContext` the way you did will bring up a set of Spark clusters with the drivers on the executors, which is not your goal I hope.

Let me know what is your goal and I would tell how to achieve this

Comment: like in mapreduce to get some value we can do job.setconf(key,val)and get it in mapper..i want somthing same like this.

Comment: SparkContext is not used to pass parameters. You can pass parameters directly or use broadcast variable. You might create HashMap object containing configurations you want to have and pass it directly to the function executing in `map` or any other transformation/action. With broadcast variables it is similar, refer to the guide: http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables

Comment: broadcast variable is preferred solution if your configuration object is big enough